# Best way to store XML data for a game in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, loader

I'm writing a game for AS3 that pulls in data from XML files, parses it and organises it into different Objects (custom AS3 Classes). It starts to get a bit tricky when I try and think of how I can store the image data, and how I can initialise it later on. At the moment I store the character's Display Object inside a custom Character sprite class. However, I thought it might actually be better to have a giant AssetLoader Class, and instead of storing the data inside a Character class, I store it one large array in the AssetLoader Class instead.

Which would be the most efficient way of doing this - considering that there could potentially be hundreds of character assets.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. You should work with what you find the most comfortable/useful. Every approach has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: The number of assets is irrelevant, the space they require in memory is. Don't keep assets in memory if you gonna have hundreds of them and all together they require a huge amount of memory.

Comment: @BotMaster I guess the only thing I can think of is having separate XML files for each level, and only loading the assets that are relevant for each level. Then when the level is over, flush everything from memory and load the next set of assets.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, having assets organized per level is generally a good idea. Depending on the size of the level, you might be able to achieve even finer granularity ( e.g.: levels are divided into areas; let's say the player starts in area A, so you load all assets for area A; now let's say he travels from A to B via some connection door; you remove all area A assets and objects from memory - you prepare them for garbage collection - and you now load assets for area B - you can have a small loading message or something to signal the transition, think of games like Diablo that have a similar approach to level loading and area navigation ).

Whether you need such fine grained loading or not is hard to say without more detail. I recommend you start with the simpler approach ( assets per level ) and improve from there on if really needed. Remember: *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil."*

**PS:** You shouldn't organize just image data per level, ideally, you should organize all level information like that. If there's no need to display level-specific information before actually getting to the said level, then pre-loading it is a waste.

**PPS:** Depending on where the game will run and the size of it, you might want to consider ditching the XML approach and using a database ( e.g.: SQLite for desktop and/or MySQL for the web ) for storing game related data ( including images ). XML tends to fall short fast and it can easily get quite cumbersome to maintain, not to mention that you might eventually want to add new features that could really benefit from a centralized DB ( e.g.: scoreboards, user statistics,  achievements, etc. ).

Answer (score 0):

Storing image data in XML is probably not a good idea. Store the image data separately in a binary format and only store IDs or URLs in the XML. Personally, I prefer storing all object data in AMF format, which makes encoding and decoding easy and very fast.

Comment: you can't store image data in xml. AMF is also not a miracle solution when it comes to fast asset access. If assets are stored locally then AMF will make the process slower since it requires an additional parsing, when used for passing data via http it requires testing to be proved faster since back end has to compress and client side decompress which adds to the overall time.

Comment: Yes you can, for example base64 encoding.

Comment: yes base64 is stored as string and requires byte loading, the only reason you would do that in xml is to purposely make the whole process as slow as possible.

Comment: Sorry, @Aaron - I should have explained a bit better. The URLs are stored in the XML, I then parse the data and use loaders to store binary data in custom Objects - then I reference them later. It still feels like an awful lot of memory consumption to store binary data for each image.

Comment: @botmaster That's exactly my point, storing image data in XML (or any text format) is not generally a good idea. And AMF way is faster and more efficient than XML, period.

Comment: @jcoulam OK I think I don't really understand what you're asking. You're asking how to store the image data in AS3 at runtime?

Comment: @Aaron There will be some images in the game that I only intend on using very, very rarely. It seems a waste to keep them in memory if i'm only going to display them every 10 minutes. So, from what I understand, the best method for me to store all of my images is to download them, store them as bitmap data, and then create a new instance of that bitmap data and add it to the stage? (I'm working in AS3)

Comment: @JCoulam It's hard to know what the best trade-off is without more specifics, but yes, for smooth game experience I've generally found pre-loading all assets is the best, otherwise you run the risk of stuttering/freezing when they are needed (or, depending on the type of game, that might not be a big deal). If there's a risk your game is actually going to reach memory limits (for example there are a lot of very large bitmaps) then it's a good idea to avoid pre-loading them all. It all depends. Sorry this answer was off the mark on what your problem was. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this static class to share large configuration XML, some runtime variables and some objects between 100s games classes:
https://github.com/inruntime/AS3-Global-Object